# Include bool in dict comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, compression

I have a function that returns a dict comprehension. I'm not sure how to get my comprehension to return both bool. Right now I have it set so that True is the value of the dictionary if x happens, but how do I incorporate False if y happens all in one comprehension?

```
    def function......:  
        print('Are these the oldest?')         
        return [dict_key: True for dict_key in dict if d[dict_key] ==0]
```

Comment: Although most people can understand what you're asking, you should include your code to show us what you've got and what you understand how to do so far - and what you might have done wrong.

Comment: You have a list comprehension, not a dict comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ternary condition inside of a comprehension:

```
{dict_key: True if <condition> else False for dict_key in ...}
```

Or you can just use the result of the condition itself:

```
{dict_key: <condition> for dict_key in ...}
```